# File Input will not upload in Internet Explorer using Bootstrap File Input

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, metronic

So I am using IE to test the file input of my page - it simply doesn't work when you submit it will pass through the correct query string which it should when you submit but the file is not uploaded to the database.

I have tested this on chrome and firefox - and both work. This is the code:

Select your document
        
            
                Select fileChange
                
                ×

I have noticed when I remove the divs/spans around the input - it works perfectly but of course then I have the inconsistency of the ugly input system which is handled differently on each browser.

Has anyone come across this before? Does anyone know any fixes.

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: I am using IE 11 for testing